# Bluetooth LE with Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I am new with Smartface, just downloaded it some hours ago, and I'm looking for a solution to make an application both for IOS and Android which will communicate with a bluetooth device (NRF8001 from Nordic Semiconductor). Until now, I worked with Phonegap but Smartface seems to be a quite good tool !
The problem is that for the moment, the only thing I can find is an example project to use iBeacons (only for IOS) but no bluetooth LE. So is there a way to develop an App with Bluetooth LE for Android and IOS ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Smartface App Studio supports iBeacon for current releases.

BLE is in our RoadMap and you can check it from the link below;

http://www.smartface.io/roadmap/